# Custom styles for Bootstrap 3 button in Ruby on Rails

Tags: html, css, ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap

I have problem with creating custom styles for bootstrap 3 buttons in my Ruby on Rails 4 app.
I have the following link:

```
= link_to t('car_configurations.index.add'), { action: :new }, class: "btn btn-lg btn-default"
```

And my css.scss file have following styles:

```
.btn-default {
  background: #ec6523;
  color: #fff;
  border: 0px;
}

.btn-default:hover {
  background: #333;
  color: #eee;
  border: 0px;
  outline: none;
}

.btn-default:active {
  outline: none;
  background: #333;
}

.btn-default:focus {
  background: #ec6523;
  color: #fff;
  outline: none;
}
```

The problem is that this styles not apply to this button. What's wrong?

Comment: Check this out:
http://www.sitepoint.com/how-to-customize-twitter-bootstraps-design-in-a-rails-app/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try loading your CSS after your bootstrap

```
<head>
<link href="bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

Then

```
<link href="YOUR.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
```